# Ошибка File "attack.py", line 2, in <module> import socks

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
$ python3 attack.py

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "attack.py", line 2, in <module>
    import socks
ImportError: No module named 'socks'
```

Что делать?
Чего только не делал, ничего не помогло.

Comment: Очевидно, что в файле attack.py во второй строке импортируется модуль socks, а интерпретатор такого модуля найти нигде не смог и выдал соответствующую ошибку. У вас почему-то есть уверенность, что данный модуль должен был найтись?

Comment: на моей основной вдс все хорошо, но тут ошибка какая-то

Answer (score 2):

Установите библиотеку [PySocks](https://github.com/Anorov/PySocks) на машину, на которой вы запускаете скрипт.

```
pip install PySocks
```